# Getting specific fields from http to our zabbix server

Tags: http, curl, get, zabbix

**Hey guys, I'm a Sysadmin and we have a api that monitor our servers and the running modules, with a get request which I'm doing with curl to address like this: http://monitoring.system.com:1234/Server/Get
im getting a huge json format string which including every running server and his status and his runing modules, im trying to transfer this information to zabbix with http agent but i want to extract only keys like server name and services what i should request in the request body?
example:
curl get http://monitoring.system.com:1234/Server/Get
{"ServersData":[{"profiles":[{"name":"Somemoudle","status":""}                                                                                  ],"id":"SomeServer","name":"SomeServer","lastUpdateTime":"2020-01-29T12:41:36.3572043","status":"Ok","met                                                                                  rics":{"cpu":{"value":15,"unit":"%","time":"2020-01-29T12:41:16.4326333Z","status":"Ok"},"memory":{                                                                                  "value":27,"unit":"%","time":"2020-01-29T12:41:16.4326333Z","status":"Ok"},"disk":{"value":0,"unit"                                                                                  :"%","time":"2020-01-29T12:41:16.4326333Z","status":"Ok"}}},{"profiles":[{"name":"Somemoudle","status":""}**

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTTP agent to fetch content from the API, then use a dependent item for each numeric item you need, using a JSONPath preprocessing to select the single value.

Example of JSONPath with the JSON you provided: `$.ServersData[0].[met rics].cpu.value`

- [Dependent items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/dependent_items)
- [Preprocessing / JSONPath](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/preprocessing/jsonpath_functionality)

Comment: Thanks for commenting, im getting an error like this:
cannot extract value from json by path "$.ServersData[0].[met rics].cpu.value": cannot parse as a valid JSON object: invalid object format, expected opening character '{' or '[' at: 'name'
what can be wrong?

Comment: you can use https://jsonlint.com/ to ensure the json is well formatted, and https://jsonpath.com/ to check your path format string